# Hosted Wiki for documentation similar to Github wiki

Tags: wiki

I want wiki similar to Github Wiki but Github Wiki is repository specific and can't be customized to remove Github navigation controls.

I would like a hosted wiki without any ads and should be easy to style/customize.

I am open to using Rails based simple wiki solution with good set of wiki features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Branchabe](http://www.branchable.com/), the hosted version of [Ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info) is probably the best wiki engine in the vein of the github wiki. This is a personal preference issue though and I don't know that there's an objectively *right* answer here.

Answer (score 1):

[MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki%20MediaWiki) is a great open-source Wiki that you could use for this, as well as just about any other Wiki solution.

Comment: I wanted Rails specific plugin but I ended up creating wiki pages by hand.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikispaces](http://wikispaces.com) seems pretty decent.

It has a free option and its layout is customizable (in the paid version). I have to say though, like most wikis, it doesn't have the best user interface (it seems better than most though).